# Sttema teechart for Mono Android .net

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I am using tee chart for .net (Mono android .net) i want to do some task on click event on chart series  but click event is not firing. and also on long click is not firing. please help me.

Comment: Please show us some code, preferably a minimal example which reproduces your described behavior. Also please tell us [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug (TM63016317) we will try to fix for the next maintenance release.